# How do I put the contents of a list in a single MessageBox?

Tags: c#, list, string, syntax

Basically, I have a list with multiple items in it and I want a single message box to display them all.

The closest I have got is a message box for each item (using `foreach`).

What I want is the equivalent of:

```
MessageBox.Show ("List contains:"+

Foreach (string str in list) 
{ str + Environment.Newline + }

                )
```

But obviously this won't work! What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 31):

You can join everything into a single string with [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx):

```
var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

However, if you don't have access to .NET 4, you don't have that overload that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`. You will have to fallback on the one that [takes an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray());
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: Use the `", "` instead of the `Enviornment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have .Net 4.0

```
string s = String.Join(",", list);
```

If you don't but have 3.5

```
string s = String.Join(",", list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Stringbuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


foreach(string str in list)
{
    builder.Append(str.ToString()).AppendLine();  
}           

Messagebox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

Regards

Comment: There is an overload of AppendLine that takes a parameter. Using that would make the code simpler. Also, there is an overload that takes an object and calls ToString on it, so there's no need for calling it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun and in case you need to do something like that with non-string collections one time - a LINQ version using `Aggregate`, which is the closest to your example syntax. Don't use it here, do indeed use `String.Join` in this case, but keep in mind that you have something in LINQ that can do what you need.

```
MessageBox.Show("List contains: " + 
   list.Aggregate((str,val) => str + Environment.NewLine + val);
```

EDIT: also, like Martinho Fernandes pointed out, it's better to use the `StringBuilder` class in cases like that, so:

```
MessageBox.Show("List contains: " + list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                                               (sb,val) => sb.AppendLine(val), 
                                               sb => sb.ToString()));
```

Comment: If you're using `Aggregate`, it's better to aggregate a StringBuilder, instead of a string: `.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb,x) => sb.AppendLine(x), sb => sb.ToString());` :P

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: that's a very good suggestion for a very wacky solution!

Comment: Consider passing `"List contains: "` to the `StringBuilder` constructor.
Add missing paranthesis at the end.

Answer (score 1):

simply you need to make a for loop for example:

```
 string total ="";
    for(int i =0; i<x.count ;i++)
   {
     total =total+x[i] +"\n";
   }
   MessageBox.Show(total);
```